# Loop Query - Not able to get lowest value

Tags: excel, vba

Not able to get the lowest value. Couldn't capture where it's missing. Please advice on the query

```vb
Sub Main()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Dim Highest As Variant
    Dim Lowest As Variant
    Dim SumTotal As Variant
    Dim Counter As Variant

    'Accept numbers from the users
RepeatPara:
    ActiveCell = InputBox("Enter Number, please")
    Let Counter = Counter + 1
    Let SumTotal = SumTotal + ActiveCell
    Let Average = SumTotal / 5
    If ActiveCell > Highest Then Let Highest = ActiveCell
    If ActiveCell < Lowest Then Let Lowest = ActiveCell
    If ActiveCell = Average Then Let Average = ActiveCell
    If Counter < 5 Then
        GoTo RepeatPara
    End If
    MsgBox "Highest " & Highest & vbCrLf & "Lowest " & est & vbCrLf & "Total " & SumTotal & vbCrLf & "Average " & Average
End Sub
```

Comment: `If ActiveCell < Lowest` => `If ActiveCell < Lowest Or IsEmpty(Lowest)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### User Entries Stats

- A `For Next` loop seems like more appropriate.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
     
    Const NumberOfEntries As Long = 5

    Dim Hi As Double
    Dim Lo As Double
    Dim Tot As Double
    Dim Av As Double
    
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 1 To NumberOfEntries
        cValue = InputBox("Enter Number, please")
        If cValue = "" Then ' User pressed cancel.
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If n = 1 Then
            Hi = cValue
            Lo = cValue
        Else
            If cValue > Hi Then Hi = cValue
            If cValue < Lo Then Lo = cValue
        End If
        Tot = Tot + cValue
    Next n
    Av = Tot / NumberOfEntries
    
    MsgBox "Highest " & Hi & vbCrLf & "Lowest " & Lo & vbCrLf _
        & "Total " & Tot & vbCrLf & "Average " & Av

End Sub
```